# Call to a java script function Regular Expression Validator to fail In asp.Net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, validation

I have a `<asp:RegularExpressionValidator>` that validates a text box but i also have a javascript function that prevents entering of non numerical values in the textbox. when  use the expression validator it works fine but as soon as i add `onkeydown="return jsDecimals(event);"` to the text box to call the `jsDecimals()` function the validator doesn't work. What am I doing wrong??

asp Code

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" CausesValidation="true" MaxLength="13" onkeydown="return jsDecimals(event);"></asp:TextBox> 

<asp:Button ID="Button5" runat="server" Text="Retrieve" CssClass="btn btn-default" OnClick="Button5_Click"/>

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" CssClass="tooltip-arrow"
      ErrorMessage="ID must be 13 Numeric characters" ControlToValidate="TextBox2" ValidationExpression="^[0-9]{13}$">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

JavaScript:

```
function jsDecimals(e) {

var evt = (e) ? e : window.event;
var key = (evt.keyCode) ? evt.keyCode : evt.which;
if (key != null) {
    key = parseInt(key, 10);
    if ((key < 48 || key > 57) && (key < 96 || key > 105)) {
        if (!jsIsUserFriendlyChar(key, "Decimals")) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else {
        if (evt.shiftKey) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
return true;
function jsIsUserFriendlyChar(val, step) {
// Backspace, Tab, Enter, Insert, and Delete  
if (val == 8 || val == 9 || val == 13 || val == 45 || val == 46) {
    return true;
}
// Ctrl, Alt, CapsLock, Home, End, and Arrows  
if ((val > 16 && val < 21) || (val > 34 && val < 41)) {
    return true;
}
if (step == "Decimals") {
    if (val == 190 || val == 110) {  //Check dot key code should be allowed
        return true;
    }
}
// The rest  
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect. Check my comment on your code below. You do not appear to be closing the function after `return true;` and you are ending up declaring the next function within the 1st one.

```
function jsDecimals(e) {

  var evt = (e) ? e : window.event;
  var key = (evt.keyCode) ? evt.keyCode : evt.which;
  if (key != null) {
    key = parseInt(key, 10);
    if ((key < 48 || key > 57) && (key < 96 || key > 105)) {
      if (!jsIsUserFriendlyChar(key, "Decimals")) {
        return false;
      }
    } else {
      if (evt.shiftKey) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return true; // <-- what's this? is there supposed to be a closing bracket after this line?

  function jsIsUserFriendlyChar(val, step) {
  .
  .
  .
```

Comment: I think that would be a mistake on my side when posting the question, let me edit the question

Comment: @SibusisoShongwe - so I guess it wasn't :)